# dynamic_template_data doesn't work with sendgrid and azure function integration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

Trying to use transactional template with azure function sendgrid integration (javaScript) , I'm sending the following object (removed email address etc.):

```
const message = 
{  
   "personalizations":[  
      {  
         "to":[  
            {  
               "email":"[MY_EMAIL]",
               "name":"Rotem"
            }
         ],
         "dynamic_template_data":{  
            "rotem_test1":"wow"
         }
      }
   ],
   "from":{  
      "email":"[FROM_EMAIL]",
      "name":"name"
   },
   "reply_to":{  
      "email":"[REPLY_EMAIL]",
      "name":"name"
   },
   "template_id":"[CORRECT_TEMPLATE_ID]",
   "tracking_settings":{  
      "click_tracking":{  
         "enable":true
      }
   }
}
context.done(null,message);
```

also tried using `context.done(null,JSON.stringify(message))` with the same result:
I get an email from the correct template but without any substitution.

when sending the exact same object using the `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`
API using postman everything works well.

would love to get help here as for what I'm doing wrong on my azure function.

Comment: Any progress? Feel free to ask if you have further question.

Comment: thanks for your solution! worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did everything correctly as you can receive email as expected.

Problem is caused by the SDK version. Property `dynamic_template_data` has just been added in latest [9.10.0 Sendgrid C# SDK](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/releases/tag/v9.10.0), but the binding extension still uses old version, which has no idea what `dynamic_template_data` is.

For 2.x function(Check Function app settings on Azure portal, see Runtime version: 2.xxx (~2)), we can install new version SDK manually before the extension is updated.

If you develop locally

1. Go to function project directory, delete bin, obj folder.
2. Edit extensions.csproj under function project, add latest version Sendgrid `<PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.10.0" />`.
3. In this directory open console(terminal,Powershell,etc), input `func extensions install` to restore packages.

Else on Azure portal

1. Stop the function app.
2. Access kudu console through Platform Features -> Advanced Tools(Kudu) -> Debug Console (CMD)
3. Navigate to D:\home\site\wwwroot
4. Delete the bin directory
5. Edit extensions.csproj, add `<PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.10.0" />` and Save the changes.
6. In console below, input `dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget`
7. After you see `Build succeeded`, start the function app.

For 1.x function(Runtime ~1), I am afraid we have to manually send email using with [sendgrid node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail), Sendgrid vesion in 1.x function is locked therefore can't be updated.